# How to systematically avoid or ignore child index out of range when reading large XML

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, xml-parsing

I am reading a large XML with more than 106.000 entries. Each entry is a group of researchers with a lot of information. I made a reading function.

However, if at any time, any information is missing, I will get

> IndexError: child index out of range

Is there a way to tell the program to **ignore** when the child is missing?

Because of the diversity of the data, I will probably have different sizes of information for each individual collected data.

It is probably not a good idea to check each time, such as:

```
if root[0]0][0][0]:
    tot_nac_2011 = int(root[0][0][0][0].attrib['TOT-BIBL-PERIODICO-NAC']
```

Here is my code

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree
extended = ElementTree.parse('0000301510136952_2014_estendido.xml')

def read_researcher(extended):
    root = extended.getroot()
    members = []
    for each in range(len(root[0])):
        group_id = root.attrib['NRO-ID-GRUPO']
        research_id = root[0][each].attrib['NRO-ID-CNPQ']
        name = root[0][each].attrib['NOME-COMPLETO']
        tit = root[0][each].attrib['TITULACAO-MAXIMA']
        sex = root[0][each].attrib['SEXO']
        tot_nac_2011 = int(root[0][each][0][0].attrib['TOT-BIBL-PERIODICO-NAC'])
        tot_nac_2014 = int(root[0][each][0][3].attrib['TOT-BIBL-PERIODICO-NAC'])
        tot_int_2011 = int(root[0][each][0][0].attrib['TOT-BIBL-PERIODICO-INT'])
        tot_int_2014 = int(root[0][each][0][3].attrib['TOT-BIBL-PERIODICO-INT'])
        tot_bbl_2011 = int(root[0][each][0][0].attrib['TOT-BIBL'])
        tot_bbl_2014 = int(root[0][each][0][3].attrib['TOT-BIBL'])
        members.append(researchers.Researcher(group_id, research_id, name, tit, sex, tot_nac_2011, tot_nac_2014, tot_int_2011, tot_int_2014, tot_bbl_2011, tot_bbl_2014))
    return members
```

Comment: Could you provide a sample XML with a couple researchers (please avoid posting the sensitive information please)? Thanks.

Comment: Here is the link [link] (https://www.dropbox.com/s/farljl3u0basvfx/0000301510136952_2014_estendido.xml?dl=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your specific question: use the exception handling via `try`/`except` and handle the relevant errors that might happen when you extract the attribute values from child elements. This is sort of the [`EAFP`](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp) programming style. There is also the [`LBYL`](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-lbyl) one.

I would also improve the code using an intermediate dictionary to handle the `Researcher` object initialization arguments, move the `group_id` from under the loop, since we are getting it from the root element.

The code:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree


extended = ElementTree.parse('0000301510136952_2014_estendido.xml')


def get_value(item, index, value):
    try:
        return int(item[index].attrib[value])
    except (IndexError, KeyError, AttributeError, ValueError):
        # TODO: log
        return None


def read_researcher(extended):
    root = extended.getroot()
    group_id = root.attrib['NRO-ID-GRUPO']

    members = []
    for item in root[0]:
        subitem = item[0]
        researcher = {
            "group_id": group_id,
            "research_id": item.attrib.get('NRO-ID-CNPQ'),
            "name": item.attrib.get('COMPLETO'),
            "tit": item.attrib.get('TITULACAO-MAXIMA'),
            "sex": item.attrib.get('SEXO'),
            "tot_nac_2011": get_value(subitem, 0, 'TOT-BIBL-PERIODICO-NAC'),
            "tot_nac_2014": get_value(subitem, 3, 'TOT-BIBL-PERIODICO-NAC'),
            "tot_int_2011": get_value(subitem, 0, 'TOT-BIBL-PERIODICO-INT'),
            "tot_int_2014": get_value(subitem, 3, 'TOT-BIBL-PERIODICO-INT'),
            "tot_bbl_2011": get_value(subitem, 0, 'TOT-BIBL'),
            "tot_bbl_2014": get_value(subitem, 3, 'TOT-BIBL'),
        }

        members.append(researchers.Researcher(**researcher))
    return members
```

Comment: Thanks. I am a newbie. With this one I also learned (**args) and I understood that Except: can return something. Thanks a lot. Best,